# Windows Azure Toolkit installer UI

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface

How to get an UI like in this installer?

Does someone see examples over the Internet?

I got no ideas what should i type in Google.

[image]

Comment: If that was not done with WPF it could.  It looks like a templated ListView with a detail template.

Comment: @BalamBalam, WPF not a problem for me. I'm trying to find an example UI with look very close to subj. And didn't succeed yet.

Comment: You can't google a format.  Start coding.  It is just some fonts and colors.  Don't you want your own look?

Answer (score 0):

there are some UI lib you can use, mostly commercial. For delicate UI, or we say highly customized, you shall draw them yourself.

Comment: indeed, but how to Google a UI very close to subj? Because it looks very cozy.

Comment: @just.011f sorry i don't know the specified UI name, there are `Robin` and `Metro`, you may try